# Anyone have success with OpenLayers and ArcGISCache?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, resolution

- OPENLAYERS

Has anyone had success using OpenLayers and the ArcGISCache layer beyond the [examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/arcgiscache_jsonp.html)?  I'd like to mix tiles with ***different resolutions*** and although they seem to scale correctly they do not translate correctly.  Code to translate the tiles appears to be missing with the exception of a % translation necessary after the scale:

```
transformDiv: function(scale) {

    // scale the layer div

    this.div.style.width = 100 * scale + '%';
    this.div.style.height = 100 * scale + '%';

    // and translate the layer div as necessary

    var size = this.map.getSize();
    var lcX = parseInt(this.map.layerContainerDiv.style.left, 10);
    var lcY = parseInt(this.map.layerContainerDiv.style.top, 10);
    var x = (lcX - (size.w / 2.0)) * (scale - 1);
    var y = (lcY - (size.h / 2.0)) * (scale - 1);

    this.div.style.left = x + '%';
    this.div.style.top = y + '%';
},
```

- ESRI

It appears that ArcGIS JSAPI has an even greater limitation...all the tiles must have exactly the same resolution.  Can someone from ESRI discuss/confirm this limitation?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that when you create a cache, every tile in every scale level is dictated by one DPI setting for resolution.  You could potentially workaround this with a bodge, but longer answer = new q.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Available_map_cache_properties/015400000414000000/